# ExoPlayer HLS set AES128 URI of key and IV not sent thru manifest of the playlist, be set separate

Tags: android, key, aes, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I am using ExoPlayer v2.8.1 to play audio HLS files. I have a link to the master playlist that looks like this :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=72000,CODECS="mp4a.40.5"
-----.m3u8
```

The code for one media source is this:

```
HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(exoPlayerCacheDSFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(audioUrl));
hlsMediaSource.addEventListener(mainHandler, mediaSourceEventListener);
player.prepare(hlsMediaSource , true, true);
player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
```

After this ExoPlayer downloads the playlist manifest from the link and starts preparing the parts to play them (when playWhenReady = true); One manifest looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="*****.key",IV=****************
#EXTINF:3.018589,
**********00.ts
#EXTINF:3.018578,
**********01.ts
#EXTINF:2.972156,
**********02.ts
#EXTINF:3.018578,
**********03.ts
#EXTINF:2.972144,
**********04.ts
.
.
.
#EXTINF:0.975222,
**********80.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Does anyone knows how can I implement a HlsPlaylistParser, or AesCipherDataSource+AesCipherDataSink or any other method so I can set the AES-128 URI and IV separately? I want to mention that all the playlist parts will have the same encryption. So my new manifest will be the same minus the line with ext-x-key:

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="*****.key",IV=****************
```

I need a sample for the implementation or a link to a documentation about this.

Help please!

Comment: If you got any solution, please share.

Comment: Hi @MdMohsin, unfortunately I have not found a solution or get any external answer. At this point I kind of given up... I was lucky that on out project, the idea of using hls with exoplayer was rejected short after we did not found a solution for this. Best of luck!

Comment: any update on this one? I am trying parse dinamically the manifest with no success